# Couchbase N1QL Query getting distinct on the basis of particular fields

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

I have a document structure which looks something like this:

```
{
...
     "groupedFieldKey": "groupedFieldVal",
     "otherFieldKey": "otherFieldVal",
     "filterFieldKey": "filterFieldVal"
...
}
```

I am trying to fetch all documents which are unique with respect to groupedFieldKey. I also want to fetch otherField from **ANY** of these documents. This `otherFieldKey` has minor changes from one document to another, but I am comfortable with getting **ANY** of these values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupedFieldKey, otherField
FROM bucket
WHERE filterFieldKey = "filterFieldVal";
```

This query fetches all the documents because of the minor variations.

```
SELECT groupedFieldKey, maxOtherFieldKey 
FROM bucket
WHERE filterFieldKey = "filterFieldVal"
GROUP BY groupFieldKey
LETTING maxOtherFieldKey= MAX(otherFieldKey);
```

This query works as expected, but is taking a long time due to the GROUP BY step. As this query is used to show products in UI, this is not a desired behaviour. I have tried applying indexes, but it has not given fast results.

Actual details of the records:

- Number of records = **100,000**
- Size per record = **Approx 10 KB**
- Time taken to load the first 10 records: **3s**

Is there a better way to do this? A way of getting DISTINCT only on particular fields will be good.

---

**EDIT 1**:
You can follow this discussion thread in Couchbase forum: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/getting-distinct-on-the-basis-of-a-field-with-other-fields/26458

Answer (score 1):

GROUP must materialize all the documents. You can try covering index

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON bucket(filterFieldKey, groupFieldKey, otherFieldKey);